# Flutter: dynamic bottom sheet height to fit content

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a bottom sheet that resizes according to the content inside it. Only thing I found regarding bottom sheet's height is how to make it a fixed amount, but I would like to fit the content anytime it changes.

Comment: have you tried to use a `Container` for the bottom sheet's body and letting that this adapts to the size of its child? Or maybe it isn't that simple... What would you say?

Comment: Tried that, but the size is approximately half of the screen (when only a column with a text and a progress indicator is its child)